# Bean Item Container Vaadin : Reorder

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I am trying to make the ordering of the exported BeanItemContainer the same with the columns visible in Vaadin Grid. I have spent 2 days already trying to find a way to do this. However, I am unable to find any solution.

This is my code :

```
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout implements View{
public static final String VIEW_NAME = "test";

private Grid grid = new Grid();
private BeanItemContainer<PeddlingBeanNestle> bean = new BeanItemContainer<PeddlingBeanNestle>(PeddlingBeanNestle.class);
private ExcelExporter exporter = new ExcelExporter();

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    setup();
}

private void setup(){
    grid.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
    grid.setContainerDataSource(bean);
    exporter.setContainerToBeExported(bean);
    exporter.setCaption("Export");
    java.util.List<Grid.Column> a = grid.getColumns();

    for (Grid.Column b : a){
        b.setHidable(true);
    }

    grid.addColumnVisibilityChangeListener(new Grid.ColumnVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void columnVisibilityChanged(Grid.ColumnVisibilityChangeEvent event) {

            if(event.isHidden()){
                Notification.show(event.getColumn().getPropertyId().toString() +" hidden");
                System.out.println(event.getColumn().getPropertyId());
                bean.removeContainerProperty(event.getColumn().getPropertyId());
            } else {
                Notification.show(event.getColumn().getPropertyId().toString() +" displayed");
                bean.addContainerProperty(event.getColumn().getPropertyId(), PeddlingBeanNestle.class, "");
            }
        }

    });

    grid.addColumnReorderListener(new Grid.ColumnReorderListener() {
        @Override
        public void columnReorder(Grid.ColumnReorderEvent event) {
            Notification.show(grid.getColumns().toString());
        }
    });

    addComponent(grid);
    addComponent(exporter);
}}
```

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception when adding the container back. I am not sure how to put the property that was deleted back.

I just want to be able to export the data in Vaadin Grid in the same order it was shown in the Grid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Is that your custom class ExcelExporter? Please provide code and stack trace of NPE. Did you consider an add-on like [TableExport](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/tableexport)?

Comment: Aside from what @SteffenHarbich said, why are you trying to remove the properties from the container? While exporting you could just check whether the current column has been hidden or not...

Comment: Can we get some feedback, @JosephRojo?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Hi! Sorry I've been busy. I was able to get past this by using TableExport's setColumn method. Thanks for pointing it out on your previous comment! at Morfic thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok. Please take the time to post a (short) answer with your solution for future reference.